# Cannot retrieve result of a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that ends in a select statement of the data I want to retrieve. I can't seem to actually fill the DataTable in the C# code. There's no exception, just an empty DataTable (not even null!).

What am I doing wrong? Is the following code accurate?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ProcName, conn)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        })
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteScalar(); 
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
    }
    return dt;
```

Comment: Have you executed the SP directly in SSMS and verified it returns data?

Comment: @DavidKhaykin yeap, it works perfectly. I get the data as I want it every time i run it. Just not when I do so in C# :(

Comment: Does the stored procedure result in multiple record sets? Also, what are you doing with `command.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski o I added cmd.ExecuteScalar() just to see if it would work. Without that line or cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() I get the same thing. No it does not it only has one set. Its the result of a select statement.

Comment: @Independent I don't understand your question. Sorry, could you expand? The command I have just has the stored procedure name and the connection string I use to communicate with the DB (the connection string is used elsewhere so it is fine)

Comment: can u try commenting out the data adapter dispose call?

Comment: You don't want to use ExecuteScalar() that returns 1 value, the one returned from the procedure with return @retval

Comment: @qamar Just tried it, same result :(

Comment: @Paul yeah LOL I know, another developer asked me to add it in to see if it would work. I didn't have it originally. In the end I get the same result. I removed it in the code I'm working with now. I shall edit my post to reflect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new  SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ProcName, conn))
using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: YES it did! I made a mistake in moving this code into mine. TY ! :D

Comment: Nice. The using statements will automatically close and dispose of your data objects, and the sqlDataAdapter automatically opens and closes the sqlConnection for you. Simples:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  <--- no executescalar 
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```